# Flutter: How to call a Future http.Post from my Login button

Tags: flutter

So far I have created my app with the pages I need and a login screen. At the moment the login screen just simply opens the first page in the app when the login button is touched (no authentication is done). I have written a small test app to get the login with http authentication working. Now I need to move the working authentication code into my app, but I'm not sure how to call the Future from the login button.

the Future is as follows: (just running local at the moment)

```
Future<Staff> fetchStaff() async {
  final response = await http.post(
      Uri.encodeFull('http://10.0.2.2:8080/modules/rmo_daMLogin'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
      body: 'rmoService=User_Login\n'
          'UserId=fred\n'
          'Password=abc123');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response, then parse the JSON.
    return Staff.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response, then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('User or Password was incorrect.');
  }
}
```

Staff is defined as a class and just contains all the fields returned by the web service.

My login page contains the following. How do I call the Future from the Login button press and if Staff data is returned ok, how do I then use the pushReplacement of the Navigator to change pages?

Thanks for any help,
Paul

```
class RmoLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  TextEditingController usernameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  Future<Staff> futureStaff;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final futureStaff = fetchStaff();

    final userField = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      controller: usernameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        hintText: "User Name",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
      ),
    );

    final passwordField = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      controller: passwordController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Password",
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0))),
    );

    final loginButton = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        child: Text(
          "Login",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style:
              style.copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => MyJobsPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff01A0C7),
        title: Column(children: [
          Text('Jobs Organiser'),
          Text('Login', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
        ]),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(36, 20, 36, 36),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/Users.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 45.0),
              userField,
              SizedBox(height: 25.0),
              passwordField,
              SizedBox(height: 35.0),
              loginButton,
              SizedBox(height: 15.0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just add an `async` to your `onPressed` function and call `var staff = await fetchStaff()` before the navigation.

Comment: Thanks @xmashallax. How do I then use the returned staff variable to test if the Navigator can be called?

Comment: Are you communicating with api service?

Comment: Yes I am. It's one i wrote myself for my web app.

Comment: Building on the suggestion from @xmashallax, I got it working. I used an if to check if the company contained anything, and if it's not null then go to the first page. Thanks for all the suggestions. Cheers.

Comment: I have the same scenario, can you share the final working code for my reference. @PaulCoshott    I need to know how to call the API call method inside raised button click and validate username password using the API returned values then redirect to multiple pages depends on authentication

Comment: @Kavi - Are you still after this code. Sorry, I was away when you sent this and I forgot once I was back. Let me know.